# Different language syntax highlighting within same file

Tags: notepad++, css, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to get simple syntax highlighting working within a file. Here's the setup.

I have an `index.php` file, which Notepad++ correctly highlights any PHP code between the `<?` and `?>` tags. Inside of this file, I have some Javascript, which is properly recognized between the `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` tags.

However, I have some CSS that is not being properly highlighted. I've noticed this with all of the "themes" I've tried with Notepad++. The code is surrounded by `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>` yet is not being understood as CSS properly.

Any ideas?

Note: Notepad++ does properly highlight individual `.css` files.

Comment: So long as it correctly highlights the mixed PHP and Javascript, there should be no problems recognizing other languages.  You might have to look at how NPP implements the mixed-language support, and then tweak the properties for all of PHP, (X)HTML, and CSS to support interleaving the languages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a program called [phpDesigner](http://www.mpsoftware.dk/phpdesigner.php) that highlights PHP, HTML, CSS, JavaScript all separately in the same document. It does code completion for each part, even if you do style="fon...".

I had to move to it since I couldn't find any other program that was so good when working with PHP (and all the other languages it uses at the same time), including Notepad++. The one thing I wish it did was syntax highlight SQL strings within PHP (it does fine with just SQL), but maybe in a future version.

Comment: i think its the only program written in delphi i like ;P easy to crack tho ;*

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried out [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) which did very well with highlighting files which contained multiple languages. In my case, it was only HTML+CSS+JS but I'm sure it would work well with PHP.

The app is not as feature rich as notepad++ but it is much more aesthetically pleasing.

The demo version prompts the user to purchase the license once in a while, but there is no time limit.

Comment: You may want to read this Meta post: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are trying to embed different languages into each other I've found tool that allows such type of configuration: http://www.freescripteditor.org/

I personally needed PHP embedded into SQL (yes, in that order).

Configuration files are human readable, so you can change them with text editor (there's also GUI in program itself).